# Why does 'FETCH NEXT CURSOR' select no data?

Tags: abap, opensql

I have the following code:

```
OPEN CURSOR WITH HOLD dbcur FOR
      SELECT  (it_attr)
        FROM  (it_from)
        FOR ALL ENTRIES IN lt_filter_key
        WHERE (it_where).
  ...
    FETCH NEXT CURSOR dbcur INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE ct_data_p PACKAGE SIZE iv_packsize.
```

When I test with *parameter A*, the correct data is displayed.
When I make the same test with *parameter B*, no data is displayed. (which is incorrect)

I have debugged the report, copied the values from `(it_attr)`, `(it_from)`, `lt_filter_key` and `(it_where)` and created my own `SELECT` with these values (from *parameter B* report execution).
In this case, data is found.

The parameters are from the selection screen:
[image]

The trace data after using only parameter B:
(No data is found)
[image]

The `SELECT` statement I created from the trace data:
(data is found)
[image]

I used the exact `WHERE` clause values in both cases.

Important to mention: after `OPEN CURSOR` command, `dbcur` recieves a value, but at `FECH NEXT CURSOR` command, `ct_data_p` remains empty.

What are the possible reasons why this may happen and what should I try?

I have read that if too many cursors are opened, an error message will appear, which is not the case here.

Comment: Did you check it_where table? May be your B values not exists on db or there are encoding problem because of some conversion filling it_where table.

Comment: I have checked (it_where) table and seems to be fine. Command OPEN CURSOR seems to also work fine, sy-subrc = 0 and dbcur recieves value 1 (Same value like when I was using parameter A).

Comment: Can you share more detail about your parameter A and B. In your code you have a lot of parameter: it_attr, it_from, lt_filter_key, it_where, ct_data_p. Which are affected by parameter by A and B.

Comment: Parameters A and B are from the selection screen. Both affect the (it_where) table.

Comment: The only reason that the SELECT doesn't return anything is that the `(it_where)` is not built correctly. The classic issue is that many values in database tables are different from the values displayed, for instance some numbers are stored with leading zeroes but displayed without them, language codes are stored as 1 character but displayed on 2 (E <-> EN), etc. Please share more details about the actual contents of (it_where) and the table, it will help us.

Comment: PS: FETCH is not the source of your problem; the same issue would also happen with SELECT.

Comment: Sandra’s idea is good: try to extract the precise values of the placeholders :a00 to :a03 from the trace. I also noticed a difference in the displayed selects: The generated one queries TSP_ID on a92, the hand-crafted one on a00. That shouldn’t make a difference for that INNER JOIN, but maybe give it a try. Plus, dumb question: ~~did you pull the plug?~~ is the package size really > 0?

Comment: Florian, you and Sandra are right. The problem is generated by the false value from (it_where), TSP_ID should have been on A00 and not A92. I did not notice that the first time.

Comment: @Florian Can you convert your comment into an answer? (as the OP confirmed it was the right answer)